# Why does iTunes Connect say that the day isn't over yet in all regions when it is?

Tags: app-store-connect, timezone

I'm trying to look up Sales and Trends data for yesterday in iTunes Connect, but it says that the day isn't over yet in all regions:

[image]

But it is:

[image]

Is it just a lag in reflecting data in iTunes Connect, or are today's clicks being attributed to yesterday? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a place, the uninhabited wildlife refuges of [Howland & Baker Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howland_and_Baker_islands) in the Pacific Ocean, territorial areas of the United States, that is in a timezone, [IDLW](https://time.is/IDLW) (International Date Line West), that is 12 hours behind UTC, `UTC-12:00`, designated [Etc/GMT+12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00#Characteristics_of_the_time_zone_which_observes_UTC-12) in the [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) [time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Though not official, it is commonly designated as [AoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth), for `Anywhere on Earth`. So called because it is the last place on earth where any date can exist. For that reason it is not uncommon for notices or contracts that involve multiple timezones to use the `AoE` timezone as the deadline. For example [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/54612/74312) on [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

At the time pictured in your question, `1:40 AM UTC, Saturday, 1 July 2017 (2017-07-01 01:40 UTC)`, the time AoE would be `1:40 PM AoE, Friday, 30 June 2017 (2017-06-30 13:40 AoE)`. That means, at the time of that screenshot, you still had 10 hours and 20 minutes until the day is over "in all regions." As of the posting of this answer, it will still be almost 6 hours until the day is over in all regions, and iTunes Connect will update their final numbers.

I have not found a way to use that timezone in the Google Calendar app, so you can't set a reminder specifically to that time without doing some adjustments of your own. You can, however, monitor the AoE time on the web. For example at the [TimeAndDate](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aoe) website, the [Time.is](https://time.is/AoE) website, or the [WorldTimeServer](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aoe) website.

Comment: I don't understand — if the day is over in UTC, then clicks should get attributed to the next day, which is 1 July. According to the iTunes Connect guide at http://help.apple.com/itc/appssalesandtrends/en.lproj/static.html : A day includes transactions that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM for the selected timezone. For example, if you select UTC time zone, total sales for January 14 includes purchases that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM, UTC on January 14.

Comment: You didn't specify which report you were trying to retrieve. Note that for some reports the same help  page says, _Time zone: Reports are based on Pacific Standard Time (PST). A day includes transactions that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM PST._ As the error message specifically says that "the day isn't over yet in all regions," it would seem that until it _is_ over everywhere the numbers aren't final, even if you're looking at a different time zone in your report. The key isn't the time zone of the report, it's that they haven't finalized the numbers so they can't make _any_ report.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick AppAnalytics are reported in UTC, always. From your screen shot, which show the option to select a timezone, I'm guessing you're accessing the Sales and Trends section of reports. If you want to compare numbers between the two reports, you need to have UTC as the timezone in Sales and Trends, so that it matches the timezone used by AppAnalytics. In either case, because the Sales and Trends data _could_ be shown for any timezone, the numbers are not finalized until all timezones have crossed into the new day. That gives a 12-hour delay for UTC-based reports.

Comment: You're right I was looking at Sales and Trends. That's the only one that has a timezone dropdown. Sorry for the mistake. So, going back to the situation in the question, can I ignore the warning and assume the data won't change later because the day is over in UTC?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick No you _cannot_ assume the data will not change. Until the day is over in all regions, _as the message says_, the numbers are __not__ final, and subject to change. UTC timezone, or even  UTC+14:00 makes no difference: The numbers are not final, and subject to change.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not due to a lag or bug. The fact is that as I write this, it is still 30 June 2017 in some regions.

For example, right now it is 10:27pm Friday night in New York.

**[EDIT]**

You may find it useful to refer to one of the many online time services, such as the [World Clock](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) to check what the time is at any given moment around thew world.

Comment: I don't understand — if the day is over in UTC, then clicks should get attributed to the next day, which is 1 July. According to the iTunes Connect guide at http://help.apple.com/itc/appssalesandtrends/en.lproj/static.html : A day includes transactions that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM for the selected timezone. For example, if you select UTC time zone, total sales for January 14 includes purchases that happened from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM, UTC on January 14.